# When creating a new .xml shouldnt a .java file be created also

Tags: android, android-intent

im new to this coding. but when i create a new layout/activity (i.e a new .xml) shouldn't a new .java file be created as well that corresponding to the new file.
like when you create MainActvity.xml for the first time the MainActivty.java is also in the SRC/com.example... folder. so im a little confused.

So what i did was create anther new .xml form file>new> Android XML file . created fine but now .java file?

i'm curious about this because when i did my intent code it wouldn't load up the page. im guessing that it wasn't "linked" with the java file or something. (

Answer (score 1):

No, it would not create a java file by itself. XML files, can be stuff other that just layouts for activity files. So, it's not necessary to have a java class for each XML file.

The one that gets created when you create a new project is just for convenience, which assumes that you will have atleast one activity class(JAVA file), and a corresponding Layout file(XML).

Answer (score 0):

No its not necessary to create .java file for every .xml file.Sometime we inflate our .xml file into existing .xml file in .java file.To show up your .xml it necessary to set it on .java file.

Answer (score 0):

```
right click on project->new->class

then add this in new class
public class newclass extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newxml);

}}

and add android name in androidmanifest file
```